# $n=5$ and average processing time per job is $20$ms. What's probability that..?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

> $n$ independent jobs are distributed by parallel computing on $n$ free
>   nodes, where the processing time $T_i$ of job $i$ is exponentially
>   distributed, $T_i \sim Exp(\lambda_i)$.
>
> Let $n=5$ and the average processing time per job is $20$ms. What's the
>   probability that the total time $X$ (or $Y$) is under $15$ms?

Because average processing time per job is $20$ms, we have $E(Y)=\frac{1}{\lambda_i}= 20$ms $=0.05 \frac{1}{\text{ms}}$

We have $n=5$: $$P(Y \leq 15) = F_Y(15 \text{ms}) = 1-e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{5}(0.05 \frac{1}{\text{ms}} \cdot15\text{ms})}$$

Is correct like that? I have no other idea..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$
Y =\sum_{i=1}^5 T_i \sim \mathcal{E}rlang(5, \lambda), 
$$
hence
$$
P(Y\le 15)=\int_{[0,15]}\frac{\lambda^5}{4!}y^{5-1}e^{-\lambda y}dy
$$

Comment: Thank you!! What mean this $Erlang$ ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution

Comment: Aha ok I don't learn this at the moment but I read about it now thank you for all! :)

Comment: I have only last question, I diden't find it in link your notation of integral

$$\int_{\left[0,15\right]}$$

is this same like $$\int_{0}^{15}$$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Just being lazy to write it in the more common way

Comment: Ok great thank again :))